# I am trying to find the all the characters including space between < > in string using regular expressions in python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to find the all the characters including spaces between < > in a string using regular expressions in python 3.6.

```
  String = ' <Hi>  Hello  <how are you>'
  pattern = re.compile (r'<(\w+)>')
  pattern.findall(String)
```

Output : ['Hi']

Since 'how are you' has spaces and does not match the pattern

So I need an output like : [('Hi'), ('how are you')]

I tried

```
   pattern = re.compile (r'<(\w+)>|<(.*)>')
```

but it gives me

[('Hi', ''), ('', 'how are you')]    # which is not what I want

Please suggest.

Comment: Try out your expression at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: pattern = re.compile (r'<(\w+.*?)>')
solved the problem.

Comment: pattern = re.compile (r'<(.*?)>')   - simplified answer, it work even if the string between < > begins with a space.

Comment: @Jthorpe - https://regex101.com/ is really cool. Thanks will use to test regular expressions.